# Do I stand a chance in US universities? How can I ask for so many recommendation letters?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters, recommendation-letter

I'm a fresh graduate with a bachelor degree in electrical and electronic engineering, currently aiming to study in the US for my masters degree. I am an international graduate from an accredited university. I graduated with a GPA of 2.61 which is low and I know it, my transcript is a combination of extremely bad grades and real good ones too, I have them all, As, Bs, Cs and Ds. I even have an F.

My question is, do I stand a chance at US universities?

I graduated from a university that is ranked among the top three in my country, I know I may have a bad record of grades, but I have been involved in scientific research group and I have also been part of the student community and club managements.

keep in mind I'm not aiming for the top ranked US universities, but I am more concentrated on the universities that have a good program regarding my area of interest.

Any advise is highly welcome here.

Also, seeing that I did bad in plenty of my courses, would it be okay to ask for a recommendation letter from a professor whom I did bad in his course?

keep in mind that I might apply to about 15 or 20 universities, that's a total of 60 letters ! How can I pull this off?

What is your best recommendations for me to conduct a strong enough application?

Comment: [This is me.](http://3dpancakes.typepad.com/ernie/2005/03/re_phd_with_low.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the admissions process work for US Ph.D. programs, particularly for weak or borderline students?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-us-ph-d-programs-particularly-for-wea)

Comment: If higher education is what you are seeking , why does it need to be in USA? Why can't you continue in your home country?

Answer (score 1):

> Also, seeing that I did bad in plenty of my courses, would it be okay to ask for a recommendation letter from a professor whom I did bad in his course?

It is generally not a good idea! What do you expect the professor to write if he only knows you through a course that you failed? Best case scenario: he tells you honestly that he can not write a strong letter for you. But he may also write a bad letter, which would seriously compromise your application.

> keep in mind that I might apply to about 15 or 20 universities, that's a total of 60 letters ! How can I pull this off?

You would of course send the same set of 2-3 recommendation letters for all your applications.

Comment: I'm going to disagree with this.  If the professor knows you well, and you know he would write a good letter for you that places your bad grade in context that would mean something.

Comment: Yes you are right, I agree that it can be a good move if the recommendation letter does explain that the bad grade was an accident. However the original statement was 'I did bad in his course', and not 'I had a bad grade at final exam despite doing top work all semester and having a good relationship with the professor'!